# Rails4 : How to assign a nested resource id to another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Model:

*order & material*
**order** has_many **materials**
material belongs_to order

*material & user*
**material** has_may **users**
**user** belongs_to **material**

Assume I create a material with id = 20 , order_id = 1

In materials_controller update action, I want to assign material id to specific users.In materials_controller update action I did it like this

```
    if @material.update_attributes(material_params)
      if @material.ready == true
        @users = User.where("is_manager = 't'")
        @users.each do |user|
          user.material_id = @material.id
        end
      end
   end
```

But attribute material_id in user did not get changed after the action.
Anybody could tell me what cause the failure to pass material id to user ?

Comment: You also need to do `user.save` after you change `user.material_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to do `user.save` after you change `user.material_id`.

```
      user.material_id = @material.id
      user.save #Saves the changes
```

That changed the attribute of `user` object, but the change has not been persisted yet. It's now a stale object which has some attributes changed. To persist those attributes, `user.save` is required.

Or you can use `update_attribute` like below:

```
if @material.update_attributes(material_params)
  if @material.ready
    @users = User.where("is_manager = 't'")
    @users.each do |user|
      user.update_attribute(:material_id, @material.id)
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is still not working after I tried user.save.  what kind of other reasons you could imagine to cause this problem ?

Comment: @MarcoSong Add logging and check your development.log for any errors - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e19d85fb70e4463b854d8d56f2f07c13

Comment: Thanks! Great way to see error messages. It show me
 --> Got errors - ["Password can't be blank", "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"] 
So when I change to use update_attibute it works!  User password validation caused the failure.

Comment: Yes. `update_attribute` works because it skips the validations. However, I suggest that you shouldn't have such invalidated records in your db.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

`update_all` updates all records in *one* SQL statement instead of loading all records into memory and sending N update queries to the database. This makes `update_all` much faster than iterating over multiple users.

```
if @material.ready
  User.where(is_manager: 't').update_all(material_id: @material.id) 
end
```

Often it is an issue, that `update_all` doesn't validate the records before updating. But in this case this behavior is actually preferred.