# Why does "user.role.save" return NoMethodError in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror, rails-console

I am trying to change a user's role from `standard` to `admin`. This is what I have been attempting so far, and I believe I am close.

```
User.last
#=> #<User id: 3, email: "c@c", role: 0> 

# set variable user to User.last
user = User.last

user.role
#=> "standard"

user.role=1
#=> 1

user.role
#=> "admin"

user.role.save
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for "admin":String

There is a lot more Ruby output, but that appears to be the important line. Clearly I am changing the role from `standard` to `admin`, but I am just not sure as how to save it.

Comment: you should call `user.save`

Comment: Your model object is `user` and not `user.role`, latter is the _attribute_,  need to call `save` on model object - More explanation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178261/rails4-how-to-assign-a-nested-resource-id-to-another-resource/39178291#39178291

Comment: Ahhhhhh so I am calling `save` on the object `user` and not on the `role`. 

Also thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Method chains don't always return what you think they do. When in doubt, split things out!

In your case, `user.role` returns a String, which doesn't implement a #save method. Instead, you want to invoke the model's User#save method. So:

```
user = User.last
user.role = 1
user.save
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but the example above should solve your problem while also explaining *why* your original code raised a [NoMethodError](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) exception.